# Colorir um range de colunas utilizando o XlsxWriter com Python

Tags: formatação, range

Tenho uma Tabela de 8 colunas. Caso apareça, em qualquer linha da coluna H, o número 1 necessito **destacar o range B:G dessa linha**.
Só consegui colorir a linha utilizando worksheet.set_row(row+1, cell_format=format1) e alinha toda onde se encontra o 1 na coluna H, ficou toda colorida (exemplo linha 21). Esta foi a melhor solução que encontrei até aqui, todavia preciso restringir a formatação ao range (B:G).

```
            if (i == etapa) and (x == 1):
                worksheet.set_row(row+1, cell_format=format1)
```

Comment: Consegui resolver aplicando o seguinte método:

Answer (score -1):

consegui resolver aplicando o seguinte método:

```
    for row in range(qt_linhas):
        nome = df.iat[row, 1]
        div = df.iat[row, 2]
        st = df.iat[row, i+2]
        st1 = df.iat[row, 3]
        st2 = df.iat[row, 4]
        st3 = df.iat[row, 5]
        st4 = df.iat[row, 6]
        x = df.iat[row, 7]
        lt_linha = [nome, div, st1, st2, st3, st4]
          
        if (i == 0) or (i > 0 and st == 'Sim'):
            if div == 'DS':
                bds+=1
            else:
                if div == 'DF':
                    bdf+=1
                else:
                    if div == 'DMJ':
                        bdmj+=1
                    else:
                        if div == 'DFJ':
                            bdfj+=1
                        else:
                            if div == 'DE':
                                bde+=1
        k = 0                        
        if (i == etapa) and (x == 1):
            for col in range (1,6)
                worksheet.write(row+1, col, lt_linha[k], format1)
                k+=1
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Poderia adicionar então como resposta aceita